# Problem with tikz foreach with veclen

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I tried to draw a poly-line based on a list of coordinates but with the code below the starting points of each segment of the line are shifted to the right and the calculation of the length with veclen of the segment somehow also increases while the actual distance is constant.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{cm}
\newlength{\tmpdim}

\begin{document}     
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) grid (8,3);

    \def\lastx{(0,2)}
    \def\vertA{(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2)}

    \foreach \x [count=\xi from 2,remember=\x as \lastx, evaluate=\x as \n1 using {veclen(\lastx,\x)}] in \vertA {
        \draw[blue, line width=2pt] \lastx -- \x node [midway,above] {\n1};
        \fill[red] \x circle (0.1);
        \node[red,below] at \x {\xi};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When I remove the `evaluate=\x as \n1 using {veclen(\lastx,\x)}` part the drawing is correct.

And additionally, how to get rid of the output from the `\def\vertA` statement?

Comment: Sorry! Perhaps I was too enthusiastic! Deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems. First of all, `\n1` is something that you can use in the `calc` syntax, but not in `evaluate=` because this expects ordinary macros, which cannot contain numbers. Then you try to apply `veclen` to coordinates of the form `(x,y)`. However, `veclen` needs components of vectors. This is the reason for the strange output you are seeing. If you loop over coordinates you need to extract their components to apply `veclen`. The following achieves this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{cm}
\newlength{\tmpdim}
\def\parsecoord(#1,#2)>(#3,#4){% 
\edef#3{#1}% 
\edef#4{#2}% 
} 
\begin{document}     
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) grid (8,3);

    \def\lastx{(0,2)}
    \def\vertA{(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2)}

    \foreach \x [count=\xi from 2,remember=\x as \lastx] in \vertA {
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\parsecoord\lastx>(\noexpand\myoldx,\noexpand\myoldy)}\temp
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\parsecoord\x>(\noexpand\myx,\noexpand\myy)}\temp
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\vl}{veclen(\myx-\myoldx,\myy-\myoldy)}
        \draw[blue, line width=2pt] \lastx -- \x node [midway,above] {\vl};
        \fill[red] \x circle (0.1);
        \node[red,below] at \x {\xi};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]